# jQuery DataTable returning JSON on Document Ready

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, datatables

I am trying to return JSON from a PHP script to populate the DataTable.

Here is the PHP script called 'api/exceptions_all.php':

```
 <?php
 $select = "SELECT '', [FOR_PARTNER], [FOR_NAME] FROM [brokerage].[dbo].[for_exceptions]";  

 $query = sqlsrv_query($dbc, $select);

 $out = array();
 while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
 {
   $out[] = $row;
 }
 echo json_encode($out);    

 ?>
```

When I pull up the file in the browser, I can see the JSON and it is in the correct format:

```
 [{"":"","FOR_PARTNER":"0000111222","FOR_NAME":"CUSTOMER1 "},{"":"","FOR_PARTNER":"0000333111","FOR_NAME":"CUSTOMER2"}]
```

Here is the jQuery I was attempting to use to retrieve the JSON:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $.ajax({
     type: 'GET', // not sure if I should use POST or GET
     url: 'api/exceptions_all.php',
     dataType: 'json',
     async: false,
     data: data,
     success: function(data)
     {
       console.log(data); // I'm guessing the success is where I should populate the table rows
     },
     fail: function()
     {
       console.log('fail');
     }
   });
 });
```

Here is the HTML where I initially set the table:

```
 <table class='table table-bordered display nowrap' id='example1' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
 <thead>
 <tr>
   <th><!--column used for editing--></th>
   <th>Partner Code</th>
   <th>Partner Name</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="tableBody">
 <!-- this is where the datatable rows should be displayed -->
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Further down in the same HTML file, I format the Datatable (now that I think about it, I'm not sure if I need this):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 table = $('#example1').DataTable({
   "iDisplayLength": 25,
   "autoWidth": true,
   "scrollX": true,
   "scrollY": 550,
   "stateSave": true,
   "dataType": "json"
 });
 </script>
```

With all of this done, I'm getting a console error that reads:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

I've had this before and was never able to recover from it.

Comment: `data: data,` in your jQuery code...Maybe you want to initialize data variable before send it through ajax or do not include it at all if is not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to pass data through AJAX to your PHP script 'api/exceptions_all.php'.

So you dont need this line in your jQuery code

`data: data`

Remove it and the error you get should disappear

Comment: It seems you are correct.  I was able to remove the error.  Now I should be able to populate the table within the success function.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: In your `success` function you now have the data that your php script returned.So you can do whatever you want with them,populate the table etc

Comment: Thank you, sir.  This has helped me greatly.

Comment: See my comment on the `success` function with `async: false`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.  As @GeorgePant says you don't need a `data` parameter if you don't have a `WHERE` clause in your SQL, since you're not passing anything to your PHP script.    Another thing is that if you are making a synchronous call (I wouldn't without good reason, especially if you're doing it simply because you don't know how to handle an asynchronous one), then you don't use the `success` parameter.  Rather, your data is returned in the `responseText` property.  This takes this form:

```
var x = $.ajax({yadayada}).responseText;
```

`success` is an internal callback function that gets called when the response is complete.  Think of it like this.  Synchronous has the form "go get this data, I'll wait until you have it."  Asynchronous has the form "go get this data, and let me know when you have it."  If you're doing the former, then all you need is the data.  If you're doing the latter, you need first a notification that the data has arrived, and then you need the data.  The `success` parameter (which, by the way, has been replaced by the `done()` function--onward and upward and all that) is that notification, and the function you attach to it has your data available to it as a parameter.

The reason that synchronous calls have been deprecated is because they prevent the user from doing anything else with the page until the call is finished.  That doesn't mean that they shouldn't ever be used.  An example of a good reason to use a synchronous call is this.  I have an application that doesn't run on the web; rather it's an internal db application that uses the browser for a container.  If a user enters a stock number in a field, I want to look up whether that stock number has already been entered or not, and message the user if it has.  I don't want the user to leave the field if they are entering a duplicate number.  This means I want to prevent browser activity while I'm looking up the number; that means a synchronous call.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is being caused because you didn't define the variable data, 
so try removing the data: data line, it looks like you're just getting a JavaScript file which wouldn't normally take a query string:

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {
   $.ajax({
     type: 'GET', // not sure if I should use POST or GET
     url: 'api/exceptions_all.php',
     dataType: 'json',
     async: false,
     success: function(response)
     {
       console.log(response); 
     },
     fail: function()
     {
       console.log('fail');
     }
   });
 });
```

Also tried to use other variable instead of data in ajax success.